# Azure Data Factory join two lookup output

Tags: azure, join, azure-data-factory, pipeline

I'm trying to create a pipeline which:

1. Gets some info from an Azure SQL Database table with a LookUp activity.
2. Gets similar info from an Oracle Database table with a similar LookUp activity.
3. Join both tables somehow
4. Then process this joined data with a ForEach activity.

It seems pretty simple but I'm not able to find a solution that sweets my requirements.

I want to join those tables with a simple join as both tables shares a column with the same type and value. I've tried some approaches:

- Tried a filter activity with items like `@union(activity('Get Tables from oracle config').output.value, activity('Get tables from azure config').output.value)` and condition `@or(equals(item().status, 'READY'), equals(item().owner,'OWNer'))` but it fails because some records doesn't have a status field and some others haven't the owner field and I don't know how to bypass this error
- Tried a Data Flow Activity approach which should be the one, but Oracle connection is not compatible with the data flow Activity, just the Azure SQL Server one [image: Orale not supported]
- I've tried to put all the records into an array and then process it through a DataBricks Activity, but DataBricks doesn't accept an array as a job input through their widgets.
- I've tried a ForEach loop for appending the Oracle result to the Azure SQL one but no luck at all.

So, I'm totally blocked on how to proceed. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Here's a pipeline overview: [image: Pipeline Overview]

Comment: Any updates? I'd like to know if you were able get over this limitation